# Randomized Number Repeats when run again LUA

Tags: random, lua

Why do I get the same randomized numbers from my previous run when I run again this code:

```
local weightsOutput = {}
for i=0, 2 do        --initialize random weights
     weightsOutput[i] = string.format("%0.4f",(2*math.random())-1)
     print(weightsOutput[i])
end
```

any problem with my code? By the way, I'm using LUA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start your program with

```
math.randomseed( os.time() )
```